# Menus not displaying horizontally

Tags: html

Now, menus are getting displayed in this way:

```
Customer
Quote
Table
```

But,i want it to display in this way

```
Customer  Quote  Table
```

http://dpaste.com/hold/183841/

Comment: @SilientGhost what changes have you made?

Comment: Can you add the html of your menu, and the relevant css to your question?

Comment: @ricebowl http://dpaste.com/hold/183841/

Comment: @bobince waht changes have you made?

Comment: @DAFFODIL http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2639510/revisions - you can click the `edited [X minutes ago]` link to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#topnav a {
  display: inline;
}
```

ps: or remove the `display: block;` you put on `#topnav a`.

Comment: @ srpt in table,it isn't displaying those both edit and delete.

Comment: That's something to do with the JS, I guess... but you could accomplish that menu much simpler - I suggest you read this article: http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/ , which will teach you how to do something like http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/ using HTML and CSS (and a minor JS snippet if you wish for it to work on non-conformant browsers [IE6. IE7?]).